# MySQL: Query for group of record with certain exclusive column value

Tags: mysql

I have the following records:

```
name                            acct_num    address     city        rep     primary
DARTMOUTH HITCHCOCK HOSPITAL    1212 MEDICAL CENTER DR  LEBANON P   Meehan    Y
DARTMOUTH HITCHCOCK HOSPITAL    1212 MEDICAL CENTER DR  LEBANON P   Johnson   N

MASSACHUSETTS GENERAL HOSPITAL  891 PO BOX 123  CHARLESTOWN P   Morrison  N
MASSACHUSETTS GENERAL HOSPITAL  891 PO BOX 123  CHARLESTOWN P   McCoy     N
MASSACHUSETTS GENERAL HOSPITAL  891 PO BOX 123  CHARLESTOWN P   Lorena    N

CLINIC PHARMACY CONTROL SUPPLY  282043  1 MEDICAL CENTER DR LEBANON P Sikes   N
CLINIC PHARMACY CONTROL SUPPLY  282043  1 MEDICAL CENTER DR LEBANON P Kang    Y
CLINIC PHARMACY CONTROL SUPPLY  282043  1 MEDICAL CENTER DR LEBANON P Tolbert N
```

Basically I need to query any hospital that does not have a primary contact (all primary='N'). So in the above records, I need to get MASSACHUSETTS GENERAL HOSPITAL since all records for this is primary='N'.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `account_prof_affiliation_view` where primary_sf='N' GROUP BY accnt_num
```

But this would just capture all records that has even just one primary='N'. What's the right SQL query to do this?

Comment: Fiddle for experiments available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/433e0/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would be this:

```
SELECT name, accnt_num
FROM account_prof_affiliation_view
GROUP BY accnt_num, name
HAVING MAX(primary) = 'N'
```

This makes use of the fact that `'Y'` sorts after `'N'`, so `MAX(primary)` will be `'Y'` whenever there is a single `'Y'` in that group.

Comment: Worked and quick too since I had more than 80k records. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a `GROUP BY`, it must contain minimum all data you selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on collation, the way [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786126/1468366) does, then you can use this:

```
SELECT accts.account_num
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT account_num FROM account_prof_affiliation_view) accts
     LEFT JOIN account_prof_affiliation_view aff
            ON (aff.primary_sf = 'Y' AND aff.account_num = accts.account_num)
WHERE aff.account_num IS NULL
```

Note that your database schema appears to be in violation of the [second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form): name, address and city can most likely be deduced from the account_num, so having a separate table for that information would be preferable. If this is because the data comes from a view, as the name indicates, and not from an actual table, then this is OK, but you still might make things more efficient by using the underlying table in the subquery above, instead of the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from account_prof_affiliation_view a
where not exists (
  select `primary` from account_prof_affiliation_view b
  where b.id=a.id
  and   b.primary = 'Y'
)
```